# Is battery enough to power the Atmega328, display, HX711

Tags: power, avr, atmega, atmega328p

I create *electric scales* that will work with small scales.

- Microcontroller: **Atmega328**
- Display: **SSD1306**
- **Load cell** + **HX711**

I want to charge this device using USB. To do this, I will use **TP4056** (allows you to charge a Li-ion battery and use this potential).

***Q: Is battery enough to power the Atmega328, display, HX711.***

**The output will be 5 volts is this enough?**

[image]

Comment: "Is battery enough"... depends on which battery. A 30mAh battery probably not, a deep cycle marine battery, yes. Which battery do you want to use? How long do you need it to run? How much current do you draw?

Comment: @Ron Beyer, What kind of battery would you recommend using? For this combination. I don't know how to determine how much current my circuit consumes. I just started doing this

Comment: You still need to answer how long you want this to run, and what you expect your current draw to be (go through your components and add up the worst-case current consumption as a base-line). I can't answer that first question for you, and you should at least be able to answer the second question (current draw).

Comment: BTW, 5V is not enough output voltage, that display takes a minimum of 7V.

Comment: @Ron Beyer,  worst-case: Atmega328 5.5 V + HX711 5 V + SSD1306 (128*64) 5V  + load cell 10V 
(if the worst-case is the highest voltage)

Comment: That's voltage... not current...

Comment: @Ron Beyer HX711 normal operation < 1.5mA, power down < 1uA //// Atmega328: Active Mode: 0.2mA – Power-down Mode: 0.1μA  Power-save Mode: 0.75μA ////  SSD1306  15mA. I can't find it on Load cell.

Comment: @Ron Beyer My English is not so good and I'm confused. Could you help me choose a battery based on those parameters? But I have another problem I can't find a datasheet for load cell (up to 1 kilogram)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The output will be 5 volts is this enough?

[SSD1306](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/SSD1306.pdf) minimum Vcc is 7 volts. So no, 5 V will **not** be enough. However if you have an SSD1306 [module](http://wiki.sunfounder.cc/index.php?title=OLED-SSD1306_Module) then it probably will be (check the documentation for your module to make sure).

> Is battery enough to power the Atmega328, display, HX711.

A single cell lithium-ion battery puts out between 3.0 and 4.2 volts depending on its state of charge. To get 5 volts from it you will have to use a voltage booster (AKA step-up DC/DC converter).